# Call onkeyup function while doing automation

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, automation

I am trying to perform IE automation using PowerShell. While automating some manual task using IE object, I am able to navigate to the website and enter value in text box, but the submit button available on website can only be triggered after a key up event is fired in that text box.

```html
<input id="txtFormID" class="TableTextAlt" type="text" onkeyup="doUpdate();"
  maxlength="10" name="txtFormID"></input>
```

Is there any way to call this `doUpdate()` function of my client's page using a PowerShell script?

Obviously I cannot edit or make any changes on client's page.

Note: I do not wish to use method like `SendKeys` to simulate key strokes as it' s not robust and needs IE window to be open and focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have an event/handler attached to an element (`onkeyup="doUpdate()"`) you can trigger it programmatically by using the [`fireEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method on the element:

```psh
$url = 'http://...'

$ie = New-Object -COM 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Navigate($url)
do { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 } until ($ie.ReadyState -eq 4)
$ie.Visible = $true

$el = $ie.Document.getElementById('txtFormID')

$el.FireEvent('onKeyUp')
```